# Template for *Proceedings of the IEEE* Journal

Tags: templates

I am not able to find the template for publications in [Proceedings of the IEEE](http://www.ieee.org/publications_standards/publications/proceedings/index.html).

Here is an example: [A Survey of BGP Security Issues and Solutions](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.157.7974&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Comment: You mean this one: http://www.ieee.org/conferences_events/conferences/publishing/templates.html?

Comment: @chl: you should post that as an answer.

Comment: @Caramdir Done. But this is just the first entry when googling `ieee template latex` (which I already have on my hard, but this is another story)...

Answer (score 3):

He said *journal*. No template will give you the Proceedings look because it is set in a commercial font: [Font Bureau Whitman](http://www.fontbureau.com/fonts/Whitman/). It is the IEEE's flagship publication, so they want to jazz it up a bit.

However, you could approximate it with a transitional typeface like Charter or Utopia.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your point. Although the word "journal" is in the title, the two other links points to IEEE Proc website and a sample article. I interpreted the question as "where can I find the corresponding Latex article template", for submitting a paper to this journal, or review. The OP is actually a CS Undergraduate, according to his profile. Such templates, like those for Elsevier, BMC, or LLNCS, are generally linked to from the authors guidelines/instructions page. The editor is generally free to apply whatever stylizing transformation to the final product in turn.

Comment: Conference proceedings are one thing, and the *Proceedings of the IEEE* is another. The IEEE's conference proceedings do not resemble this journal.

Comment: That's well put, indeed! I didn't notice that subtlety. I will retract my answer. My bad... (And my +1)

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe that there is currently a LaTeX template for the current style of *Proc. IEEE* shown in your example, but there was a class file written by Michael Shell that implemented the previous style of *Proc. IEEE* (which was used by all the *IEEE Transactions* journals as well): http://www.michaelshell.org/tex/ieeetran/

Gregory Plett also created a class file for the previous *Proc. IEEE* style: http://mocha-java.uccs.edu/ieee/

Comment: Do you know if these files are actually up to date? The last update on the first link date back to 2008, but seems to have v.1.7a. The 2nd link looks interesting as it provides a lot of illustrations, and finally point back to IEEE main website (so +1).

Answer (score 0):

This wizard tool provides a way to select IEEE template according to the title. Users can use this tool as a template selector for downloading IEEE transactions template from the IEEE web site. - https://template-selector.ieee.org/secure/templateSelector/publicationType

Alternatively, you can also use IEEE templates from other sources that provide it. Examples are:

- [Typeset IEEE](https://typeset.io/formats/ieee/default-template-for-ieee-journals/7571580208800f8572b783b996ff7646) - can download in LaTeX and MS-Word
- [LaTeX templates.org](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/ieee) -  - can download in LaTeX only

[image: IEEE template selector]